# Add date to Database with different date system settings

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, datepicker

I want to save the date from a datepicker to the sqlserver.

But when different date formats are used on the pc, the date changes the day and month.

For example:

> Short date format on my system: dd-MMM-yyyy
>
> DatePicker: 01-july-2015
>
> When I save the date to my database the will be saved as 01-07-2015.

But when i change my system date format, the day and month are changed

> Short date format on my system: dd-MM-yyyy
>
> DatePicker: 01-july-2015
>
> When I save the date to my database the will be saved as 07-01-2015.

Code:

```
//Set dateTimePicker to DateTime variable
DateTime dateSales = dateTimePicker1.Value;
 
// Create SQL connection
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString());
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

//Create query with values and execute query
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into CarsSellout (CustomerID, dateSales) VALUES ('" + CustomerID + "', '" + dateSales + ")";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

I'm aware of the SQL query who is not parameterized!

How can i fix this? no luck so far with programmatically changing formats..!

Please help me!!

Comment: If you parametrize and use `date` or `datetime` types in SQL and C# this problem will be handled automatically and correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [bad habit as choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

If you save your `DateTime` values to your SQL Server, save them as a `DateTime`. Do **NOT** save them with their string representations.

That's why, change your `dateSales` column type to `datetime` or `datetime2` and pass your `dateSales` value *directly* to your [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

```
DateTime dateSales = dateTimePicker1.Value;

using(var con = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString()))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into CarsSellout(CustomerID, dateSales) VALUES(@id, @date)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CustomerID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateSales;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And I strongly suspect your `CustomerID` should numeric type (based on it's name) that's why wrote it's parameter as `SqlDbType.Int` in my example. If it is not (which isn't since you use single quotes with it), change it's parameter to relevant [`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the explaining code! My dataType of dateSales is 'date'.

Comment: @JP..t That means your `dateSales` column type _only_ saves date part of your `dateSales` variable.